# Why is current user also getting returned after using the $ne

Tags: meteor

On the server i got this

```
Meteor.publish('allusersbutme', function () {

  // every except the current use
  if (Meteor.userId) {

    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId}}, {fields: {profile: 1, 'services.facebook': 1}});
  }

});
```

on the client I have

```
Meteor.subscribe('allusersbutme');

Template.discover.helpers(
        {
            users: function () {
                return Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
            }
        });
```

The users helper is still returning the current user.  This works if I do `return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId}}).fetch()`. This is abit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Meteor.userId()` inside a publish function, right?  I thought you had to use `this.userId`.  Besides, `Meteor.userId` is a function, so your query is making sure that `_id` is `$ne` to a `function`... which I imagine is always true.

`Meteor.publish` docs for `this.userId`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_userId

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thanks . i used this.userId and Meteor.userId() is a function

Comment: But still i get the current user!. only way to work this is to do it on the client.

Comment: @MurWade, the signed in user is always published to the client, and the collections on the client will contain the union of all published documents, so you always have to use the `{_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}}` selector on the client if you don't want the signed in user.

Comment: @PeppeL-G agree. i have done it on client. i just like to keep everything consistent . like all those rules on the server. but it doesnt hurt just for this. thanks ma man